# While loop not exiting even though it should

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop

I've written some code but the while loop doesn't exit?

```
#include <iostream>

#define TriangleNumber(x) (x * (x + 1)) / 2

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int idx       = 0;
    int n_factors = 0;
    int triangle_num = 0;
    while (n_factors < 3)
    {
        int n_factors    = 0;
        triangle_num = TriangleNumber(idx);
        for (int i = 1; i <= triangle_num; i++)
        {
            if (triangle_num % i == 0)
            {
                n_factors++;
            }
        }
        idx++;
    }
    std::cout << "Number with greater than 3 factors = " << triangle_num;
    return 0;
}
```

Expect to exit at idx = 3 and triangle number 6.

Comment: `int n_factors    = 0;` -- How many times is this specified?

Comment: Helpful reading (and probably a duplicate): [Shadowing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621785/shadowing-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re-declared the exact same variable name twice, so the `n_factors++` is referring to the one inside the inner loop. Remove `int` from the inner loop, and your program will output

> Number with greater than 3 factors = 6

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TriangleNumber(x) (x * (x + 1)) / 2

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int idx       = 0;
    int n_factors = 0;
    int triangle_num = 0;
    while (n_factors < 3)
    {
        n_factors    = 0;
        triangle_num = TriangleNumber(idx);
        for (int i = 1; i <= triangle_num; i++)
        {
            if (triangle_num % i == 0)
            {
                n_factors++;
            }
        }
        idx++;
    }
    std::cout << "Number with greater than 3 factors = " << triangle_num;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining n_factors twice, outside and inside the while loop. The one you are incrementing is the one inside the loop while the one that the loop checks against is the outsider, which is always zero in your case i.e always less than 3.