# C++ If-statement variable scope

Tags: c++, if-statement, scope

I have this function which when I run it it gives me the wrong answer due to the scope of the variable `numer`. Is there a way to use only one return statement for this function. I had to separate return statement which gave me the right answer (you can see with the `//`).

```
double calc_real_root(double a, double b, double c, double disc, double operation)
{ 
  double denom=2*a;
  double numer;
  if (operation == ADD)
  {
    double numer = -b + sqrt(disc);
    //return numer / denom ;
  }

  else 
  {
    double numer = -b - sqrt(disc);
    //return numer / denom ;
  }
  return numer / denom ;
}
```

Comment: Don't create a new numer in a nested scope that hides the outer numer. Just use/assign to the existing numer from the outer scope, i.e. numer = ...; rather than double numer ...

Comment: `operation == ADD` (which looks like `enum`) but with `double operation` :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *shadowing* the *outer* variable `numer` with an *inner* variable of the same name.

See: [Shadowing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621785/shadowing-variables)

You can assign to the variable `numer` from the inner scopes, instead of declaring new variables.

```
double calc_real_root(double a, double b, double c, double disc, double operation)
{ 
  double denom=2*a;
  double numer;
  if (operation == ADD)
  {
    // Assign to `numer` without declaring new variable.
    numer = -b + sqrt(disc);
  }
  else 
  {
    numer = -b - sqrt(disc);
  }
  return numer / denom ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've declared *three* variables named `numer`:

1. The initial one is uninitialized and is used in the return statement
2. The one in the body of the `if`
3. The one in the body of the `else`

The solution is to remove the `double` from the `if` and `else` bodies.  For example,

```
numer = -b + sqrt(disc);
```