# What happens to a variable of a member function having same name as that of a private data member of the same class?

Tags: c++

When i compile the code below i don't get any error and on debugging it initializes the class data member `a` of class
`abc` to zero. Can someone just tell me how is the compiler differentiating between the two. I dont see it happening in runtime.

```
//A function friendly to two classes (finding maximum of objects of 2 classes(one data member in class)
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class abc; //Forward Declaration
class xyz
{
  int x;
  public :
  void inivalue(float);
  friend float max(xyz,abc);
};

class abc
{
  int a;
  public :
  void inivalue(float);
  friend float max(xyz,abc);
};

void xyz::inivalue(float y)
{
  x=y;
}

void abc::inivalue(float a)
{
  a=a;
}

float max(xyz m,abc n)
{
  if(m.x > n.a)
  return m.x;

  else
  return n.a;
}

int main()
{
  system("cls");
  xyz o1;
  abc o2;
  o1.inivalue(10);
  o2.inivalue(20);
  cout<<"The maximum of 2 classes is : "<<max(o1,o2)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: ... It's called "shadowing".

Comment: Its also pretty unfriendly to someone trying to read your code if it ever gets any more complex than what you have.

Comment: Helpful reading: [Shadowing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621785/shadowing-variables)

Comment: You're just assigning the parameter to itself.

Comment: Your compiler can warn you about shadowed variables. In short turn on all warnings. Treat warnings like errors (it will pay off in the long run).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called "variable shadowing".

When you do that, the local variable `a` "shadows" the class variable. The compiler will use the local variable, so in the `inivalue` function of the class `abc` you're just setting the parameter value to itself.

The `a` member of the class is unitialized when it is used in the `max` and the code will result in Undefined Behaviour.