# How to reverse a linkedlist and print it?

Tags: c++

I was trying to reverse my linked list and my code is below. I created a linked list inserted members then  print the linked list, reverse it and then print the linked list as an output.

```
using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class linkedl{
public:
    void insertl(node *head, int data);
    void reverse(node *head);
    void print(node *head);
private:
    node* head;
};

void linkedl::insertl(node *head, int data) {
    node *he = new node();
    he->data = data;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = he;
        he->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        he->next = head;
        head = he; 
    }
}

void linkedl::reverse(node* head) {
    node *next, *prev, *current;
    current = head;
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;

        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }

    head = prev;
}

void linkedl::print(node *head) {
    node *w = head;
    while (w != NULL) {
        cout << " our linked list member" << w->data << endl;
        w = w->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *r = NULL;
    linkedl ha;
    ha.insertl(r, 1);
    ha.insertl(r, 2);
    ha.insertl(r, 5);
    ha.insertl(r, 7);
    ha.insertl(r, 9);
    ha.insertl(r, 11);

    ha.print(r);

    ha.reverse(r);
}
```

I was expecting 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11 in the first round and in the second round I was expecting a reversed output 11, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1. However my coding is not having any compling errors but doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: Note: Compiler errors are only the beginning of the adventure.  Normally I get some really good advice from [cranking up the diagnostic level](https://godbolt.org/z/9bPv6boq3), but here it only spots a memory leak. Next thing to do is to go snooping in on what the code's really doing with a debugger.

Comment: @Henok Mulugeta The data member head of the list is not initialized. And this declaration    node* r=NULL; does not make sense.

Comment: Mark I eyeball spots `void linkedl :: reverse(node* head)`. Why pass `head` into a class that should already know its `head`?

Comment: Future note: this also passes `head` by value. What `head` points at is passed by a form of reference, but `head` itself is just a plain old variable and is copied. Anything you do to change the value of this copy of `head` inside the function will be lost when the function exits and the copy is destroyed.

Comment: The `head` parameter conceals and replaces ([shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621785/shadowing-variables)) the `head` class member. Removing the `head` parameter cleans up most of the code's problems: https://godbolt.org/z/eYxzz1zTh

Comment: Future proofing note: Before you go too much further, adding a destructor to `linkedl` to clean up the memory leaks for example, please read about [the Rule of Three (and Friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You cannot write C++ effectively without a firm understanding of the rules of Three, Five, and Zero.

Comment: Unrelated: Unless you are using a pre C++11 compiler, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code, some of which have already been pointed out in the comments. Here's a minimal change to ensure your code runs: You only need to pass "head" by reference, and print in reverse order.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
  int data;
  node *next;
};
class linkedl {
public:
  void insertl(node *&head, int data);//change
  void reverse(node *&head);//change
  void print(node *&head);//change

//private:        //unused variable (Edit: suggestion from comment)
//  node *head;
};

void linkedl ::insertl(node *&head, int data) {
  node *he = new node();
  he->data = data;
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = he;
    he->next = NULL;
  } else {
    he->next = head;
    head = he;
  }
}
void linkedl ::reverse(node *&head) {
  node *next, *prev, *current;
  current = head;
  next = NULL;
  prev = NULL;

  while (current != NULL) {
    next = current->next;
    current->next = prev;

    prev = current;
    current = next;
  }
  head = prev;
}

void linkedl ::print(node *&head) {
  reverse(head);//change
  node *w = head;
  while (w != NULL) {
    cout << " our linked list member" << w->data << endl;
    w = w->next;
  }
  reverse(head);//change

}

int main() {
  node *r = NULL;
  linkedl ha;
  ha.insertl(r, 1);
  ha.insertl(r, 2);
  ha.insertl(r, 5);
  ha.insertl(r, 7);
  ha.insertl(r, 9);
  ha.insertl(r, 11);

  ha.print(r);

  ha.reverse(r);
}
```

What's more if you want to insert the elements to the end you should also keep a pointer to the tail.
Here is a more idiomatic implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
  int data;
  node *next;
};

class linkedl {
public:
  linkedl() : head(nullptr) {} // Constructor to initialize head
  ~linkedl(); // Destructor

  void insertl(int data);
  void reverse();
  void print();

private:
  node *head;
};

// Method to insert a new node at the beginning
void linkedl::insertl(int data) {
  node *he = new node{data, nullptr};
  if (head == nullptr) {
    head = he;
  } else {
    he->next = head;
    head = he;
  }
}

// Method to reverse the linked list
void linkedl::reverse() {
  node *next, *prev, *current;
  current = head;
  next = nullptr;
  prev = nullptr;

  while (current != nullptr) {
    next = current->next;
    current->next = prev;

    prev = current;
    current = next;
  }
  head = prev;
}

// Method to print the linked list
void linkedl::print() {
  reverse();
  node *w = head;
  while (w != nullptr) {
    cout << "Our linked list member: " << w->data << endl;
    w = w->next;
  }
  reverse(); // Reversing it back to its original state
}

// Destructor to release the dynamically allocated memory
linkedl::~linkedl() {
  while (head != nullptr) {
    node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
  }
  cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
}

int main() {
  linkedl ha;
  ha.insertl(1);
  ha.insertl(2);
  ha.insertl(5);
  ha.insertl(7);
  ha.insertl(9);
  ha.insertl(11);

  ha.print();

  ha.reverse();
  ha.print();
  
} // Destructor is called automatically when ha goes out of scope
```

Comment: Recommendation: remove the `head` member from the first example to emphasize the fact that it's unused as long as a different `head` is passed in as a parameter. Probably also worth a few lines of text to introduce the asker to the concept of shadowing.

Comment: A slightly more idiomatic insertion would probably be to remove the `node` constructor and then do `void linkedl::insertl(int data) { head = new node{data, head}; }`. I also recommend not using `NULL` and to prevent accidental copies/moves.